# Find what script is running in php

Tags: php, apache

The following Apache 2.4 processes seem to consistently be using up the CPU.  While I appreciate that it tells me PHP is the command is there a way to see what script is running to eat up this much CPU.

```
Pid Owner   Priority    CPU %   Memory %    Command
17695 (Trace) (Kill)    seger   0     36.24   0.53  /usr/bin/php
17383 (Trace) (Kill)    seger   0     31.01   0.52  /usr/bin/php
17488 (Trace) (Kill)    seger   0     29.75   0.53  /usr/bin/php
17377 (Trace) (Kill)    seger   0     28.88   0.54  /usr/bin/php
17475 (Trace) (Kill)    seger   0     26.34   0.52  /usr/bin/php
17692 (Trace) (Kill)    seger   0     25.88 0.36    /usr/bin/php
18770 (Trace) (Kill)    seger   0     16.64   0.51  /usr/bin/php
1023 (Trace) (Kill) mysql   0     15.94   1.65
```

Comment: are you using task manager or a terminal to get that info? If you're using a terminal, what command are you using?

Comment: This is the stats in cpanel/whm, I have SSH access, no gui. @Webeng

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong you are asking for this

```
ps ax | grep *.php

pstree | grep php
ps aux | grep php
ps xuww | grep php
```

it will list all running php process.

Comment: I'm looking for more along the lines of for example what PID 17695 is actually running, what script specifically?

Comment: when you run these two commands (ps aux | grep php , ps xuww | grep php) you will find each of the details what is the name of file and related things.

Comment: I'm not seeing the file name being run unfortunately :-(

Comment: where are you running those commands do you have putty or something. are you able to login as root?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in via Putty and sudo to root

Comment: Okay run only this command ps aux | grep php one more time and tell me what are you getting.